# NAN sometimes for same image on training my yolo tensorflow model for loss

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, yolo

[Success instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoV5I.png)I am running my custom YOLO (you only look once) network implemented purely in Tensor-flow. However, the loss calculation for the same image varies with each time I feed it to the network. The confidence and width becomes NAN sometimes. Any suggestion on how to debug this and what could be possible cause for this behavior?
[Failed instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iV3C.png)
I have checked my input image is in range 0-1. placeholders data type is float 32.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel Initializer of the network was constrained to output in between 0-1. This solved my NAN problem.